# Handling special characters while parsing with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jdom-2

I have a xml below that I'm parsing with JDOM 2.0.5

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><order><BGP1>true</BGP1><BGP2>Metro_C&amp;amp;C</BGP2></order>
```

Now while trying to get the value of the tag  using node.getValue() where node is of type Element, it's giving me the node value as

```
Metro_C&amp;C and not Metro_C&amp;amp;C
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It's doing it's job. The node value *is* `Metro_C&amp;C`. If your document contained `A&lt;B` then the node value would be `A<B`.

Comment: How to stop this behavior?

Comment: Why do you want to stop that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct, your expectation is wrong. The text value of the node is `Metro_C&amp;C`. When you encode this as XML, the `&` character must be replaced with `&amp;` since it has a special meaning for XML.

But my feeling is that the input data is already corrupt. The text value should probably be `Metro_C&C` which would give the XML encoded value of `Metro_C&amp;C`. Patterns like `amp;amp;` suggest that someone encoded the data twice.